# Equal number of rows/columns are needed for something to be considered in the center

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to develop my understanding of mathematics.

As I am learning, I have noticed a minuscule detail while drawing grids.

Unless the number of rows and columns are equal and odd in number, there cannot be a perfect center `( I hope I make sense).`

Is there a formula for this in linear algebra?

Here is a visualization of my statement.

[image: grid]

Comment: What you say is true, but I don't see any relation to linear algebra.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If you label the columns $1,2,...,n$ and $n$ is odd, then the middle one is labeled $\dfrac{n+1}2$, and the same holds for rows, but, if $n$ is even, then $\dfrac{n+1}2$ is not an integer

Comment: @saulspatz, The only thing that I could relate to the grid was linear algebra since they deal with matrixes. Although, if you have a suggestion, into what is more appropriate, please share.

Comment: Can you articulate what you mean by perfect center?  Does a $1\times3$ grid have one?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner let me try (math noob here). Yes (I think), a grid of 1x3 has a perfect center. The length from the left-hand side to the center should cancel out with the right-hand side to the center (the highlighted square).

Comment: So perhaps you wish to say the numbers of rows and columns are odd but not necessarily equal?

Comment: Yes, they must be odd not equal.

Comment: Embedded in the arguments that a center is not a point, which is not the "classic" interpretation center is a point.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that, instead of the "wordly" description that you gave, you want a pure equation? I can give it to you! Let $m$ and $n$ be the number of rows and columns, respectively. Then
$$
\text{A center exists}\qquad  \Leftrightarrow \qquad \exists a, b\in \mathbb{N} : m = 1+2a ~\text{and}~n=1+2b
$$
Satisfied?

Comment: Yes, @MattiP., I wanted to see how a pure equation for the statement would look like. For me, as a person trying to understand mathematics, would you mind breaking down the equations in words? 

Some symbols used are unfamiliar to me and might be to upcoming readers, so it would help if you could breakdown the equation.

Thank you for taking the time so far.

Comment: @KreshnikHasanaj There are several ways of writing this condition in mathematical terms. My version tries to clearly show that the parameters $m$ and $n$ are odd; "An odd number is an integer when divided by two, leaves a remainder of one". Therefore, if the number $x$ is odd, that means that it must be of the form
$$
x = 2y+1
$$
where $y$ is an integer (whole number). Therefore, we can say that the condition is: There exists an integer $y$ so that $x=2y+1$. The symbol "$\exists$" is read "there exists" ... Is it clearer now?

Comment: @KreshnikHasanaj Perhaps a simpler condition still would be
$$
\text{A center exists} \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad m, n \equiv 1 \mod 2
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot @MattiP. ❤️, very well explained. Your equation made me curious about learning some more logic symbols.